# how to save a state of imageview which is in custom adapter

Tags: android

I have a Image View in my custom Adapter of my Recycle View and i am setting the visibility of image view by doing long press on Recycle View its works fine the problem i am facing that when is set the Visibility true and close the app or go to second activity the visibility goes to false the thing i need when i close the app or change the activity the visibility remain the same..i am new to android

```
 public class RecycleViewAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.RecycleViewHolder> {
private List<FileName> fileNames;
private Context context;
private OnItemClicked onClick;

public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, List<FileName> fileNames) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fileNames = fileNames;
}

@Override
public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewGroup mainGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    RecycleViewHolder listHolder = new RecycleViewHolder(mainGroup);
    return listHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final FileName model = fileNames.get(position);
    RecycleViewHolder mainHolder = holder;
    mainHolder.title.setText(model.getShorttext());
    mainHolder.note.setText(model.getName());
    mainHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick.onItemClick(position);

        }
    });
    mainHolder.setLongClickListener(new LongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position) {
        }
    });
    if (fileNames.get(position).isVisible()) {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != fileNames ? fileNames.size() : 0);
}

public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick) {
    this.onClick = onClick;
}

private void showPopUpMenu(final int position, final View view) {
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menuLock) {
                fileNames.get(position).setVisible(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getRootView().getContext());
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alertbox.setView(input);
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",null);
                final AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.create();
                dialog.show();
                dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String collect = input.getText().toString();
                        DBhelper dbhelper = new DBhelper(context);
                        String pass = dbhelper.searchpass(collect);
                        if(collect.equals(pass))
                            {
                                fileNames.get(position).setVisible(false);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        else if (collect.equals(""))
                        {
                            input.setError("Hello");
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}

public interface OnItemClicked {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public class RecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView note;
    public CardView cardView;
    public ImageView imageView;
    LongClickListener longClickListener;

    public RecycleViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.note = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.note);
        this.cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setLongClickListener(LongClickListener lc) {
        this.longClickListener = lc;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        showPopUpMenu(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        this.longClickListener.onItemLongClick(getLayoutPosition());
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: use sharedpreference or any static variable to save the state of image. so that any you visit to your activity you see your image in last state you saved.

Comment: can u help me with the code i never used sharedpreference ?

Answer (score 0):

in the above code you are hiding the every image if the list then obviously you have to save state of image visibility in your list. you should no need to hide the image. on long click.

add a new variable as boolean in FileName like: imagevisibility

add a condition in onBindViewHolder()

```
 if(model.getImageVisibility())
{
holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} 
else 
{
 holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

 mainHolder.setLongClickListener(new LongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position) {
        }
    });
    if (fileNames.get(position).isVisible()) {
        FileName model = fileNames.get(position);
model.setImageVisibility(true);
    } else {
        model.setImageVisibility(false);
    }
fileNames.set(position,model)
notifydatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I never worked with Sharedpreference can u give me the working code..It will help me a lot

Comment: I have boolean Variable name visible and i assign it false